# Не компилируется Qt

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь скомпилировать проект любой выдает такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и каталог сборки подсвечивается красным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ещё новичок и впервые работаю с Qt,найти нужного и понятного объяснения не смог.

Comment: На втором скриншоте слева по центру возле слова Desktop есть красный кружочек. А это говорит, что компилятор и компания (Kit) неверно настроены). Вполне возможно, что студтийный компилятор Вы забыли поставить. Это объясняет Ваш баг.

Comment: Студийный компилятор? Как его поставить?

Comment: просто установите 2015 студию community (она бесплатна для многих видов использования). Скачать можно на сайте майкрософта, но чуточку нужно будет поискать (они упорно везде 2017 предлагают)

Comment: Наверное поэтому,потому что у меня как раз 2017 стоит,а на неё нет